# VHDL - WAIT ON <signal> statement

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to work through an example of the WAIT ON  statement. Every time I try to compile my code the the compiler, Quartus II gives me the following error message.

> Error (10533): VHDL Wait Statement error at T1.vhd(23): Wait Statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword

The model Architecture is below. Its function is not important only the reason why the compiler is asking for a UNTIL statement. All the examples I have seen, internet and books show its use as such below:

```
ARCHITECTURE dflow OF T1 IS
SIGNAL middle   : std_logic;
BEGIN
P1 : PROCESS IS
BEGIN
        IF CLK = '1' THEN
            middle <= input;
        END IF;
    WAIT ON CLK;
END PROCESS P1;
OUTPUT <= MIDDLE;
END ARCHITECTURE dflow;
```

Comment: Synthesis is allowed to restrict the range of VHDL constructs it accepts. In this case, `wait until rising_edge(clk);` is probably accepted, as implied by the error message. NOTE that `wait on` is problematic if it requires detecting both clock edges, regular FPGA hardware can't support that. If you are required to use `WAIT ON` ... simulate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond is `wait on clk` equivalent to `wait until clk'event`, and hence ambiguous in the context of synthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic problem here is that the line

```
WAIT ON CLK;
```

is waiting for *any* type of event on `CLK`. This could be a transition from `'H'` to `'1'`, for example, or it could be either a rising OR falling edge of `CLK`. In either of these cases, there is no real hardware in the FPGA that can work in this way. It may seem obvious to you that you are looking for a rising edge, because of the `if CLK = '1'` line, but this is not how the synthesis tool is seeing it.

By adding an `until`, you can narrow down which particular event you are interested in, hopefully selecting something that can actually be realised in the FPGA. Examples:

```
wait on clk until clk = '1'; -- Detect a rising edge, OK (ish, see below)
wait on clk until clk = '0'; -- Detect a falling edge, OK (^^)
```

This method is analogous to the `clk'event and clk = '1'` technique of edge detection. This is not a recommended method, because you can get a simulation mismatch with reality due to the simulator responding to transitions from `'H'` to `'1'` (among other possibilities), something the hardware cannot do.

The recommended method of detecting edges is with the `rising_edge` and `falling_edge` functions:

```
wait until falling_edge(clk); -- OK, no ambiguity here.
```

Finally, the whole structure represented here looks pretty non-standard. The common way to write a clocked process is like this:

```
process (clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    -- Do something
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Hi Jeff and thanks for your time putting together a really good answer.